# Create 2 types of resources using the same view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 2 models (and resources) - Institute and Admin.

I want to have a view with 1 submit button that creates 2 types of resources. Would I need to have 2 separate forms? An example would be great!

Also, what naming convention should this view use (given that it creates 2 types resources).

There is a "has-many through" association between Institute and Admin.

Comment: Your question is too abstract. Yes, most likely, you will need two forms because, again most likely, they will be rooted to different controllers. On the other hand, your resources can be pretty similar and only have a different type, such as Admin and User when both use a User model and have a user_type field. It all depends.

Comment: Is there relation between 2 types of resources ? 1-n, 1-1 OR n-n ?

Comment: The 2 models are Institute and Admin. There is a "has-many through" association between Institute and Admin.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a design pattern called `Form Object`.

https://robots.thoughtbot.com/activemodel-form-objects

With a Form Object, you can create a class that represents the form, validate the data and then persist to the resource (or resources) that you need.

There's also a gem called [Virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) for that. For me, it's a overkill if what you want is simple. You could just create a `ActiveModel` model and do your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

```
Would I need to have 2 separate forms?
```

Answer is Non. you can make one form nested.

So example : Gessing your "has many through" association like this: One institue has many admins throuth mettings

**Models :**

```
class Institute < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mettings
  has_many :admins, :through => :mettings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mettings
end
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mettings
  has_many :institues, :through => :mettings
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :mettings
end
class Metting < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :institue
  belongs_to :admin
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :institues
end
```

**Controller :**

```
def new
  @institue= Institue.new 
  @metting= @institue.mettings.build
  @admin = @metting.build_admin
end

def create
  Institue.new(institue_params)
end


def institue_params
   params.require(:institue).permit(:id, mettings_attributes: [:id, :metting_time, admin_attributes: [:id ] )
end
```

**Views can be called _form.erb.rb included in edit.erb.rb:**

```
<% form_for(@institue) do |institue_form| %>
  <%= institue_form.error_messages %>
  <p>
    <%= institue_form.label :name, "Institue Name" %>
    <%= institue_form.text_field :name %>
  </p>

  <% institue_form.fields_for :mettings do |metting_form| %>
    <p>
      <%= metting_form.label :metting_date, "Metting Date" %>
      <%= metting_form.date_field :metting_date %>
    </p>

    <% metting_form.fields_for :admin do |admin_form| %>
      <p>
        <%= admin_form.label :name, "Admin Name" %>
        <%= admin_form.text_field :name %>
      </p>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <p>
    <%= institue_form.submit 'Create' %>
  </p>
<% end %>

<%= link_to 'Back', institues_path %>
```